# Creating a template double-linked list C#

Tags: c#, winforms, templates, linked-list

I need to implement a program that receives various input data( I do the program in WindowsForms, I made the type selection via button), adds them to a double-linked list, sorts it and outputs it to the listBox). However, when creating a double-linked list object in the button class, this list is not seen by other methods from the form class.(this is logical). I would like to create a template list object in the form and then bring it to a specific type after clicking the button. Is there any way to implement this? For now, all I can think of is creating lists of various types that will end up empty. And the sorting/output call will have to be rewritten for each list.

```
D_List<int> massiv1;
D_List<int> massiv2;
D_List<string> massiv3;
D_List<string> massiv4;
D_List<double> massiv5;
D_List<double> massiv6;
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        massiv1 = new D_List<int>();
        massiv2 = new D_List<int>();
        Gen<int>(ref massiv1, ref massiv2);
    }
//... for each list
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        M5<string> sort2 = new M5<string>();
        D_List<string> sortedd = new D_List<string>();
        string s;
        Optim<string>(massiv4, sort2, out sortedd, out s);

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        utility.Vivod(ref sortedd, listBox1);

        label11.Text = s;
        label12.Text = sort2.kolvo_srav.ToString();
        label13.Text = sort2.kolvo_perest.ToString();
    }
 //... for each list
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're really trying to do here.  You're asking a lot of questions in your test that don't have much to to with the title of your question.  A code sample demonstrating the problem might help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

It's hard to say without code but it seems like you should make use of inheritance for this. Polymorphism is designed to solve this kind of problem.

Your data presumably shares some features (for example, to be sorted it would need some kind of order to be defined). Put these into a base class and inherit that in each of subclasses hat represents the data.

As an example:

```cs
class BaseItem: IComparable
{
   public int CompareTo (object obj);
}

class DecimalItem: BaseItem
{
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
   //override CompareTo if necessary
}
```

Now instead of making a separate list for each type of data, you would make a single list of BaseItems and add whichever type the data actually is to this list.

If you are not using subclasses for your data (eg. they are primitive types) you could probably just make your single list of type IComparable.